# Calculated Column with If Statement

Tags: sql

I have a table with these columns:

UserName
TotalTransactions
Sku

I want to create an auto-generated column called Over:

If SKU is abc and TotalTransactions > 6,000, then Over is True:

```
UserName        TotalTransactions  Sku  Over
joe@mysite.com  6001               abc  True
```

How do I add a calculated column with an If statement? Here is my code:

```
select settings.UserName, SUM(TransactionCount) as TransactionCount, settings.SettingValue as Sku,
CASE WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'abc' AND TransactionCount > 6000 
 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END As Over
from jma_qb_trans_count trans
Inner Join jma_settings settings on settings.UserName = trans.UserName
where settings.SettingName = 'QB:JMAWebStoreSku' and settings.SettingValue != ''
Group by settings.UserName, settings.SettingValue, Over
Order By settings.UserName
```

When I use this code, I receive this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Over'.
```

Comment: why not have the column and add the data when your criteria is true

Comment: what do you want to happen if the sku is not abc or less than 6,000

Comment: I need multiple case statements. I need a case for over 1,800, over 6,000, over 18,000, and over 30,000.

Comment: Add square-brackets to your table name [Over]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you are looking for (Add to Select statement):

```
CASE WHEN SKU = 'abc' AND TotalTransactions > 6000 
     THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS Over
```

Comment: Hi, that seems right. I am getting a syntax error with AS Over. Please see new code.

Comment: what rmdbms system are you using

Comment: SQL Server Azure. I get expected STRING, QUOTED_ID

Comment: Try adding square brackets to your [Over] - this way SSMS doesn't mistake the string for something else.